# I'm 27 years old with an Economics BA, is it too late for me to switch to Mathematics?

Tags: advice, career-development

The last 2 years have been very difficult for me, finishing with a very late BA in an area that I really don't like. I found a decent job in clinical trials as a data coordinator, but I was always fascinated with maths and found myself performing quite well in the classes that I managed to get accepted in during my BA (Multivariable Calculus, College Linear Algebra and Analysis). I have been thinking for the last year whether I want to pursue mathematics on a Graduate level (Ph.D and all), but since I turned 27 last month, I'm wondering whether it is already too late, and that I won't really be successful in the field.

Do you guys think that it is still a road worth taking? I was planning on accumulating more math courses at an undergrad level before taking on a Masters, then a PhD...which would take so much time it makes my head spin and scares me to no end.

Thank you.

Comment: I started my PhD in mathematics when I was 32.  One of the students in the cohort above me was in his late 50s when he graduated.  It is never too late.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237002/too-old-to-start-math

Comment: I believe that the question you should answer is 'If you are going to receive a Ph.D in math, what topics do you want to study?'

The answer to this question will provide good starting point for you to compare pursuing Ph.D in math with other career/job options.
For example, take a look at some of the topics presented by Richard E. Borcherds:
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCIyDqfi_cbkp-RU20aBF-MQ.

Comment: **Wrong close reason. Please close this as [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/72538)**.