# Do only certain people exceed at math well?

Tags: self-learning, education, philosophy, learning

It's obvious if you look around that math has always been one of the toughest subjects in all areas, from federal-traditional public schools to simply people learning it as an autodidact, hobby, or as a skill to improve themselves. Is there any known foundational standing as to why this is? Why do some people seem to love math, and others seem to stay away from it like a virus?

That brings the big question: Is math only for certain people beyond a certain point? Can everyone really be a rocket scientist, math scholar or the such if they try hard enough?

We know just about anyone can IMPROVE at math, but when getting serious here ... can anyone really exceed beyond the bar-level (high school requirements, college, or calculus-level)?

If so, wouldn't more people do it? It's avoided like a virus, even at college level. It is learned simply to pass a test and then it's discarded as much as possible after.

Do only certain people exceed at math well?

Comment: This question would be a great fit for [math educators stackexchange](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @dtldarek Hey! Never knew that stack exchange existed.

Comment: Try the educators site; meanwhile, i never told a student they could not do it. I did know, often enough, that the student lacked background and could not do it at the pace the class would be setting. Well, you can get more varied observations from current teachers.

Comment: **Wrong close reason. Please close this as [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/72538)**.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Mathematics is a distinct or specific inclination, just like anything else. Exchange the word math with the name of any other craft, skill, art, or subject, and you'll be able to see what I mean. Knowing how to read and write, and do basic calculations, is fundamental, but literature and mathematics go well beyond that, and only a few people have an actual inclination towards them. Just like only a few people have a special inkling for learning history, practicing medicine, repairing cars, or dancing ballet, etc.

> *Can everyone really be a rocket scientist, math scholar or the such if they try hard enough?*

No, because feelings $($like repulsion or disgust$)$ are part of being human. People can't be force-fed things they revile. Mathematicians themselves do not all like the same fields, in case you haven't noticed.