# Soft question regarding studying and dyslexia

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, learning

Recently (as a finalist undergraduate) I discovered I am dyslexic (slow processing disorder  and  poor short term memory). This came as no surprise but simultaneously as a massive shock. This has obviously changed the way I think about learning maths and makes me realise how much more time I spend working on problems, studying and learning compared to my peers (before the diagnosis I just assumed this was down to me being lazy or not motivated enough). Learning new concepts always seems initially impossible, taking in and becoming comfortable with definitions / theorems and the motivation for them. I have a few questions I have been thinking about recently:

1. I find talking aloud, as if I'm explaining the content to a new student the most effective way for me to learn and wondered if any of you have techniques that help you study (dyslexic or not)?
2. Are there many dyslexic people that continue into post-graduate study and beyond (Specifically mathematics) ?
3. Is it worth it to continue, if you know you're incredibly slower at learning and becoming comfortable with new theories / concepts?

(Apologies if this question is not relevant)

Comment: This might also be relevant at https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would be skeptical of the diagnosis, since believing it makes failure excusable.

Comment: You might wish to read this: https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/the-advantages-of-dyslexia/ More directly related to mathematics is this: https://toomai.wordpress.com/2014/09/17/dyslexic-mathematician/

Comment: I don't know how much faith to put in this top ten list: http://numberdyslexia.com/top-10-famous-scientists-with-dyslexia/

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful: https://www.speld-sa.org.au/information/dyslexia-and-maths-topmenu-108.html But of course you should be getting advice from trained professionals, not from random strangers on a website.

Comment: Have any of those links been helpful, kam?

Comment: Are you still here, kam?

Comment: I have sought after and found professional advice, I only asked because I wanted to hear others experiences or opinions. The reason I asked here was because of the large exposure to specifically maths students and professionals so, personally, I think it is fitting. Forgive me for asking.

Comment: And yes. The links were helpful. Thank you :)

Comment: Good, I'm glad the links were helpful. You might have been more forthcoming about having already taken professional advice, and about your reasons for posting here.

Comment: You're right! Apologies. I guess I assumed saying discovered would imply that I sought out and got a formal examination. I should have been clearer. But yes, this was just about me hearing about others' experiences and tools to help study, maybe even a source of inspiration too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do only certain people exceed at math well?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823319/do-only-certain-people-exceed-at-math-well)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can an older person become an expert in math?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72538/can-an-older-person-become-an-expert-in-math)